# how to split date and time in json?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am getting datetime like this 2012-02-06 16:30,2012-02-08 16:45,2012-02-10 16:30 in json.
here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if($this->Date) : ?>
var date = JSON.parse('<?=$this->Date?>');
$.each(date, function(index, value) {
    switch(index) {
      case 0:
        $("#Date").val(value);
        $("#Time").val(value);
      case 1:
        $("#Date1").val(value);
        $("#Time1").val(value);
      case 2:
        $("#Date2").val(value);
        $("#Time2").val(value);
     }
});
<?php endif; ?>  
</script>
```

here i want to pass date in date filed time in time field.
please help me out

Comment: are you sure you are getting `$this->Date` as the json string

Comment: *I don't want to live on this planet anymore...* Your `switch` block in there is a *huge* WTF. What you need is `$('#Date' + index)`; likewise for `Time`. Then you only need a case for `index==0` if you can't rename those fields to `#Date0`/`#Time0`

Comment: Hi swapnilsarwe, yes i am getting json string..

Comment: @ThiefMaster This is what I suggested below.. It would only work if he re names his first set of date/time inputs with a `0` in their IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would change the id of `#Date` and `#Time` to `#Date0` and `#Time0` to keep things uniform. That way you can get rid of your `switch` statement altogether and do something like this, which is much less coding, and expandable for more items without changing the code.

The key to your question is the `split()` function which will split your date string into an array of pieces.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if($this->Date) : ?>
        var date = JSON.parse('<?=$this->Date?>');
        $.each(date, function(index, value) {

            // Split the Date/Time string into an array with two items
            //(0=date, 1=time)
            var pieces = date.split(' ');

            $("#Date"+index).val(pieces[0]);
            $("#Time"+index).val(pieces[1]);
        });
    <?php endif; ?>  
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Dutchie, when i split date and time i m getting like this 2012-02-06,16:30. what can i do?

Comment: Isn't that what you are looking for? You're seeing it written out with a comma because it is an array of two items. Did you update these lines? `$("#Date"+index).val(pieces[0]);` and replace `value` with `pieces[0]`?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

this may work :

```
    var new_arr = [];
    var a = "2012-02-06 16:30,2012-02-08 16:45,2012-02-10 16:30".split(",");
    for(var i =0; i<a.length; i++)
    { 
      new_arr.push(a[i].split(' '));
    }
   console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: What!? This code doesn't even do anything. You are looping the same number of times as there are characters in your string, and trying to split each character into an array split by a comma?? Not only does this not address the poster's question, it answers an entirely different question.

Comment: @Dutchie432 - That's what I thought at first glance, but the first line has `.split()` on the end. So shreedhar interpreted the question the way it sounded to me, like the original string needed to be split into three date/times first.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, why would he be splitting on a comma in the second split statement? Still makes no sense. it should be a space.

Comment: yeah, i do agree, it should be space for second split.

Comment: Still most of this code is pointless as it only reproduces the loop the poster has already going. The `split()` line is all that matters, and this code yields an array, where that is not needed. Frankly this is more confusing than anything for someone who clearly needs help with the basics (the poster).

Comment: wont it produce a array which has date and time seperately? what is it making confusing?

Comment: Because the question is asking how to split a string into two pieces. What you've done is reproduced the loop differently and rather than showing the poster how to populate his inputs with the correct values, you've shown him how to create an entirely new structure that he will then have to loop through again in order to populate. Don't get me wrong, this code will "function" properly, and if the data is needed again later, the object might be useful. But for the sake of this question, and most general practice, this is overly complicated and not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = '2012-02-06 16:30';
var date_parts = date.split(' ');
# date_parts[0] <- date
# date_parts[1] <- time
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `date_parts[0]` and `date_parts[1]`

Answer (score 1):

if string contains valid date you just can convert it to Date object.

```
  d = new Date("2012-02-06 16:30")
```

then you should have access to all methods of Date object.

- getTime() - Number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 @ 12:00 AM
- getSeconds() - Number of seconds (0-59)
- getMinutes() - Number of minutes (0-59)
- getHours() - Number of hours (0-23)
- getDay() - Day of the week(0-6). 0 = Sunday, ... , 6 = Saturday
- getDate() - Day of the month (0-31)
- getMonth() - Number of month (0-11)
- getFullYear() - The four digit year (1970-9999)

Comment: How is this better than just performing a `split()` on the string? The values are simply being placed into text boxes.

Comment: Just talking about another option. It might give you more flexibility in future.